# No dual boot option, no boot priority order

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot, wubi

I installed Ubuntu yesterday. I partitioned my C: when it was asked to give memory allocation to Ubuntu. The version is 12.04. I was able to install Ubuntu completely:

> Ubuntu is successfully installed. Restart you computer.

I restarted and there was no Ubuntu option. Windows 7 also asked for a boot repair. So I did that too. I then wanted to change my boot priority order to Ubuntu but couldn't find it in BIOS section.

I allotted 20GB to Ubuntu and it is deducted from C: but I couldn't see the partitioned drive in Windows 7. Wubi was working fine before on PC with dual boot option.

I used Linux Live key creator to boot my PC through pen drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't install Grub to the correct location. You can do this by booting the USB again and do it manually, or run a tool like [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) if you're not sure you want to mess with Grub.

Manual method:

1. Boot from your Ubuntu USB
2. Select "Try Ubuntu"
3. Identify the partition you installed Ubuntu on, mount it and install Grub to the drive MBR:

e.g.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l | grep '[\t ]83[\t ]' | awk '{print $1}'
/dev/sda5
ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Notes: the first command identifies any linux partition (MBR disk only), but only works with a single all-in-one partition (which you apparently have). The argument for `fdisk` is lower case `-L`. In my example I've set the linux partition to `/dev/sda5`. If this is different for you, make sure you adjust the next line.

PS even though you tagged your question as Wubi, I am ignoring that as it seems irrelevant. If you actually installed inside Windows with Wubi, then your question is unclear and should be edited. In this, case ignore my answer.

Comment: I did this and it was pretty easy.Boot form the same USB you used to install Ubuntu(no changes to the usb).Type in your terminal "sudu apt-get install grub" and it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Atul That command would install `grub` (grub legacy) and remove `grub-pc` (grub2). You don't want to do that.